# Specify URL path as a variable for a REACT SSR applications built manually (i.e. NOT using NextJS )

Tags: reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering

*Note: I am not using NextJS for my SSR application. I also did not use create-react-app to create my application.*

I have a React Server Side Rendered (SSR) application which was hand built (as apposed to using a tool like create-react-app).  I use WebPack to bundle up the server side code and the client side code.  *I followed the excellent Udemy course  https://www.udemy.com/course/server-side-rendering-with-react-and-redux/ to understand how to create a React SSR application*

**My Application**

*Application structure*

[image]

*webpack.base.config.js*

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        use: 'file-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          cwd: __dirname,
        },
      },
    ],
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
};
```

*webpack.client.config.js*

```
const path = require('path');
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const baseConfig = require('./webpack.base.config.js');

const config = {

  entry: './src/client/client.jsx',

  output: {
    filename: 'client-bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
  },

  plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {
          from: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'styles'),
          to: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
        },
      ],
    }),
  ],
};

module.exports = merge(baseConfig, config);
```

*webpack.server.config.js*

```
const path = require('path');
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const webpackNodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const baseConfig = require('./webpack.base.config.js');

const config = {
  target: 'node',

  entry: './src/server/server.js',

  output: {
    filename: 'server-bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
  },

  externals: [webpackNodeExternals()],
};

module.exports = merge(baseConfig, config);
```

*Routes*

```
{
    ...Home,
    path: '/',
    exact: true,
},
{
    ...Page1,
    path: '/page1',
    exact: true,
},
```

*Client Side Routing*

```
<BrowserRouter>
  ...
</BrowserRouter>
```

*Server Side Routing*

```
<StaticRouter context={context} location={req.path}>
    ...
</StaticRouter>
```

*Server Side generated HTML template*

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">${content}</div>
    <script src="client-bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

*package.json scripts*

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node build/server-bundle.js",
  "build": "npm-run-all --parallel prod:build*",
  "prod:build-server-bundle": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js",
  "prod:build-client-bundle": "webpack --config webpack.client.config.js",

  "dev": "npm-run-all --parallel dev:*",
  "dev:run-server": "nodemon --watch build --exec node build/server-bundle.js",
  "dev:build-server-bundle": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --watch",
  "dev:build-client-bundle": "webpack --config webpack.client.config.js --watch",
  "lint": "eslint ./src --ext .js,.jsx"
},
```

*Running my application*

I run the application locally using

```
npm run dev
```

My application URLs are therefore

```
http://localhost:/     
http://localhost:/page1
```

**My Requirements**

I would like my application to have a customizable URL path, for example "/a/b" so that my URLs would be

```
http://localhost:/a/b 
http://localhost:/a/b/page1
```

or if my path is "xyz" my URLs would be

```
http://localhost:/xyz 
http://localhost:/xyz/page1
```

**How to i enable a custom base path in my React SSR Application.**

*What i tried*

I hardcoded a path in my application in the HTML, and routers, i..e

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="a/b/styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">${content}</div>
    <script src="a/b/client-bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>


<BrowserRouter basename="a/b/">     
  ...
</BrowserRouter>


<StaticRouter context={context} location={req.path} basename="a/b/"> 
   ...
</StaticRouter>
```

But this does not work, going to either of the following

http://localhost
http://localhost/a/b

renders my home page with no stylesheet applied and no client side bundle. This is because neither of the following can be found and return a 404

```
http://localhost/a/b/styles.css
http://localhost/a/b/client-bundle.js
```

Furthermore, if i use a link to invoke the router, the URL for the styles and client-bundle has the path twice, i.e.

```
client side navigation to 
   http://localhost:8080/a/b/contact

means styles and client-bundle request urls are
    http://localhost/a/b/a/b/styles.css
    http://localhost/a/b/a/b/client-bundle.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add an env variable basePath and then use that to set your routes.

*Routes*

```
{
    ...Home,
    path: `${process.env.basePath}/`,
    exact: true,
},
{
    ...Page1,
    path: `${process.env.basePath}/page1`,
    exact: true,
},
```

Now, if your basePath is '/a/b', your index component will be available on `yourdomain/a/b/` and page1 will be available on `yourdomain/a/b/page1`

Comment: How would that work in the client bundle as there is no process.env on the client side

Comment: `process.env ` is available on client side. See [this doc](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-9-4#new-environment-variables-support) and the [example here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/environment-variables). If you not on next 9.4, you can use `dotenv` and use technique mentioned [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/9371) to set it up.

Comment: Those links are for "NextJS", I am specifically not using "NextJS" (I have written a version of my app in NextJS previously but my current task is to write it without using Next). I am writing React Server Side Rendering using just React and Express and WebPack.

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad, I forgot about that you had your own setup. In that case, you will need to expose your env to client as well through webpack. You can use [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) for that. You can use [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#readme) to define your envs in a file and then expose them using definePlugin. See [here](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#config) on how you can obtain a parsed env to pass to **DefinePlugin**. Note that `dotenv` is not necessary, you can expose env any way you like.

Comment: P.S There is a shortcut for DefinePlugin to set envs. See [Environment Plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/)

Comment: Ironically that is what I have been trying over the last 3 days. :)  In `webpack.base.config.js` I read in a variable `const BASE_URL = process.env.BASE_URL ? process.env.BASE_URL.toString().trim() : '';`.  I then use this for the publicPath `output: { publicPath: BASE_URL, }` and in the DefinePlugin
`plugins: [  new webpack.DefinePlugin({ 'process.env.BASE_URL': JSON.stringify(BASE_URL),    }),  ],`   When I test this locally it works perfectly (I added the BASE_URL to the package JSON scripts so the ``build` and `start` get the variable.).

Comment: BUT the problem I have now is that it fails when I try and run it from my Docker container. It appears the env var is not found.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217748/discussion-between-se22as-and-hassaan-tauqir).

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have much knowledge of dockers so can't help you there. You might want to raise another question on that. But if your app works fine in production build locally, then this is probably not a react/webpack issue.

Comment: Thank you. The one thing I am confused about is build time verses runtime regarding these changes added to WebPack. As I understand it, WebPack is only called at build time. Does that mean I only need the environment variable set when building my application? I presume I do not need it when running my application.  When I added the same support in my NextJS application, i set the environment variable at RunTime and it is read in the next.config.js file.

Comment: Yes, webpack is only used to build your bundle e.g. react apps. And yes, you need to expose your env variables at build time and then they are accessible anytime on your client. Env vars are generally not expected to change during run time, so you have to set them once during build phase. Env vars change gradually, and when they do,  you can just rebuild your application again.

Comment: As for next.config.js, it is just a config file provided by next to consumers, to provide extra configuration on their own webpack/build process, which is not exposed to consumers. It only runs at build time. According to [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/introduction), "It gets used by the Next.js server and build phases, and it's not included in the browser build." So if you define env using next.config.js, they are just exposed to their in-built webpack. They just provide an option to expose some vars to server only and some to client. Behvaior has changed in v9.4.

Answer (score 0):

Hassaan Tauqir's post above which I have marked as the answer helped me refine the solution. Thank you to Hassaan.

**package.json**

Change the scripts for the PRODUCTION environment to have the BASE_URL specified.

```
"prod:build-server-bundle": "cross-env BASE_URL=/a/b webpack --config webpack.server.config.js",
"prod:build-client-bundle": "cross-env BASE_URL=/a/b webpack --config webpack.client.config.js",
```

Note: You have to use "cross-env" otherwise this will not work on every operating system, therefore I had to install "cross-env" first

```
npm install cross-env
```

I left the DEVELOPMENT scripts unchanged as I do not need a path when testing locally

```
"dev:build-server-bundle": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --watch",
"dev:build-client-bundle": "webpack --config webpack.client.config.js --watch",
```

**webpack.base.config.js**

*Reading in BASE_URL*

The "BASE_URL" is accessible in "webpack.base.config.js".  I added code so that I can handle the "BASE_URL" being specified with a trailing slash or not.

```
// Set up the BASE_URL parameter, ensuring it does not have a trailing slash
let BASE_URL = '';
if (process.env.BASE_URL) {
  BASE_URL = process.env.BASE_URL.toString().trim();
  if (BASE_URL.substr(-1) === '/') {
    BASE_URL = BASE_URL.substr(0, BASE_URL.length - 1);
  }
}
```

*publicPath*

In the "module.exports" add the "output" section and add the "publicPath" setting.  "publicPath" allows you to specify the base path for all the assets within your app, for example I have images which I reference in my application using the following code.

```
import myImage from '../images/myImage.png';
....
<img src={myImage } alt="myImage " />
....
```

"publicPath" must end in a trailing slash, therefore if we have a BASE_URL I append a / otherwise I leave it empty.

```
output: {
    publicPath: (BASE_URL) ? `${BASE_URL}/` : '',
},
```

For more information on "publicPath" see https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/

*webpack.DefinePlugin*

In the "module.exports" add the "webpack.DefinePlugin" setting the environment variable to be passed through to the reset of the application

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.BASE_URL': JSON.stringify(BASE_URL),
    }),
],
```

For more information on "DefaultPlugin" see https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/

**Server Side Routing**

Add the "basename" to the server side router, whose value is the variable specified in the "DefinePlugin" in the webpack config file

```
<StaticRouter context={context} location={req.path} basename={process.env.BASE_URL}>
    ...
</StaticRouter>
```

**Client Side Routing**

Add the "basename" to the client side router, whose value is the variable specified in the "DefinePlugin" in the webpack config file

```
<BrowserRouter basename={process.env.BASE_URL}>
    ...
</BrowserRouter>
```